# Can I use a company's timestamping server with self-signed certificates?

Tags: certificate, self-signed, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser, timestamping

I'm interested in signing my Silverlight XAP with a self-signed certificate, so it can auto-update. I haven't tried yet, but figure I can create a certificate easily with [this question/answer I found on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows).

But it's not clear to me what the timestamp server does and can I use a timestamp server from a company (for example, [the one from Comodo](http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode)), even if I didn't buy a certificate from them, but self-signed my certificate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting bits and pieces together I found [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872105/alternative-timestamping-services-for-authenticode) by [BruceCran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76093/brucecran):

> Any timestamp server can be used: I recently switched from my issuer's
>   timestamp server to Verisign since I found that GlobalSign's server
>   was unreliable. Furthermore, Thawte don't run their own timestamp
>   server but recommend people to use Verisign's.

So, yes I assume I can use any timestamp server.

As for what a timestamp server does, it is [explained by Comodo](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/code-signing-faq.html):

> Since key pairs are based on mathematical relationships that can be
>   cracked with a great deal of time and effort, it is a well-established
>   security principle that a digital certificate should expire. Your
>   Digital ID will expire one year after it is issued. However, most
>   software is intended to have a lifetime of longer than one year. To
>   avoid having to resign software every time your certificate expires,
>   companies have introduced time stamping services. When you sign code,
>   a hash of your code will be sent to Certification Authority to be time
>   stamped. Once your software has been time stamped, you will not need
>   to worry about resigning code when your Digital ID expires. Microsoft
>   Authenticode allows you to time stamp your signed code so that
>   signatures will not expire when your certificate does.

So your certificate expires, but your code doesn't.