# Change the name of file using windows batch script (keeping extension)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, file-extension

I wanted to change the name of the file keeping the extension. The condition was if timestamping failed may be because of unavailability of TSAs, then I wanted to mark the file as 'unsigned'

The code for signed was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872105/alternative-timestamping-services-for-authenticode)

Scenario is:

batch file : **sign.bat**

arg2 : **file1.exe**

expected output
if timestamping fails then need to mark the **'file1.exe'** as **'file1_unsigned.exe'**
After all the searches what I did was,

```
echo Timestamping failed , marking the file as unsigned. 
set file_name=%2
set unsigned_file_name=%file_name:.exe=_unsigned.exe%
ren %file_name% %newfilename%
```

This kept the file extension by adding a string to original file .

Is there a better way to do this ? may be using pattern matching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directely do :

```
 echo Timestamping failed , marking the file as unsigned.
 echo ren "%2" "%~n2_unsigned%~x2"
```

Comment: Yes , this helped. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FOR /F` to achieve this. Take a look at this code:

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ("something.txt") do (
    echo %%~nf
    echo %%~xf
)
```

This will output:

> something
>
> .exe

So in your case you could do this:

```
echo Timestamping failed, marking the file as unsigned. 
for /f %%f in ("%2") do (
    ren %%f %%~nf_unsigned%%~xf
)
```

`~n` returns the name and `~x` the extension of a file. This construct might be longer but it will perfectly work for any file and not only for `.exe`.