# post-build event with multiple if/copy combinations only execute if first file does not exist

Tags: delphi, post-build-event

Given the `bin\` directory inside the Delphi project contains the files `Cert.pem` and `Key.pem`, the below Delphi post-build event only copies both files if `C:\Binaries\Cert.pem` does not exist:

```
if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem (copy bin\Cert.pem $(OUTPUTDIR))
if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem (copy bin\Key.pem $(OUTPUTDIR))
```

As soon as `C:\Binaries\Cert.pem` exists, the `Key.pem` file is never copied.

How can I solve this in the post-build event?

Edit: unlike my [2014 post](https://wiert.me/2014/11/20/delphi-prebuildpostbuild-events/), this is indeed possible using parentheses. See my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with Delphi post-build events is that they are not batch files.

It means that statements that look like lines are being concatenated by the Delphi IDE into one big `&` ampersand separated statement. This ensures the commands are executed in sequence, as per [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> ```
> commandA &  commandB      Run commandA and then run commandB
> ```

So this is the actual statement that gets executed:

```
if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem (copy bin\Cert.pem $(OUTPUTDIR))&if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem (copy bin\Key.pem $(OUTPUTDIR))
```

The problem here is that now the second `if` is seen as a continuation of the "then" part of the first `if` statement: the second `if` never executes when the `$(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem` exists.

What helps is a little known feature that you can wrap each command inside parentheses. Normally this is to allow one command to span multiple lines (especially for `if`, and `for`..`do` loops), but it also works on one line.

Wrapping each line having an `if` statement inside parentheses ensures they become standalone statements not affecting the other lines, even if they are being concatenated with `&` ampersand separators.

In the dialog it looks like this:

```
(if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem (copy bin\Cert.pem $(OUTPUTDIR)))
(if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem (copy bin\Key.pem $(OUTPUTDIR)))
```

That way, the IDE translates it into one statement:

```
(if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem (copy bin\Cert.pem $(OUTPUTDIR)))&(if not exist $(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem (copy bin\Key.pem $(OUTPUTDIR)))
```

Now it works as intended:

- When `$(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem` exists but `$(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem` does not, only `$(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem` is copied
- When `$(OUTPUTDIR)Cert.pem` does exists but `$(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem` does, only `$(OUTPUTDIR)Key.pem` is copied
- when neither exist, both are copied
- when both exist, neither are copied

I did not know this "trick" when writing my 2014 post [Delphi prebuild/prelink/postbuild events](https://wiert.me/2014/11/20/delphi-prebuildpostbuild-events/), so I need to write an update for it.

Searching for batch file parentheses [site:microsoft.com -site:social.technet.microsoft.com -site:answers.microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch%20file%20parentheses%20site%3Amicrosoft.com%20-site%3Asocial.technet.microsoft.com%20-site%3Aanswers.microsoft.com&cad=h) did not reveal it in the official documentation, but I am not surprised as it grew hysterically, instead of being designed. Or like [the Old New Thing attributes h2g2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091029-00/?p=16213):

> Much like the universe, if anyone ever does fully come to understand Batch then the language will instantly be replaced by an infinitely weirder and more complex version of itself. This has obviously happened at least once before ;)

The best documentation I could find was at [Parenthesis/Brackets - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html):

> Parenthesis can be used to split commands across multiple lines. This can make code more readable. Variables will be evaluated for the code block just as if the command was a single line.
>
> ```
>  (command)
>
>  (
>   command
>   command )
> ```
>
> Things that break inside parenthesis
>   The CMD shell does not use any great intelligence when evaluating parenthesis, so for example the command below will fail:
>
> ```
> IF EXIST MyFile.txt (ECHO Some(more)Potatoes)
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: ...and to fix `IF EXIST MyFile.txt (ECHO Some(more)Potatoes)` all you need is to add a little carrot ...   `IF EXIST MyFile.txt (ECHO Some(more^)Potatoes)` (ok, caret then...)

Comment: Was able to solve my issue, thanks for the detailed post!

Answer (score 5):

Use multiple build events instead of putting both commands in the same event.

---

**Executing the source lines of a build event.**

I can cut this short very easily: build events are not batch files.

What happens is that all lines in your build event are concatenated together using ampersand (&) signs which are used to execute multiple commands on one command line.

This means that all the fancy control structures (if statements, setlocal, for loops) are not possible inside build events.

---

ref: Pasted from a blog post: [Delphi prebuild/prelink/postbuild events](https://wiert.me/2014/11/20/delphi-prebuildpostbuild-events/) written by Jeroen W. Pluimers

Makes me wonder why you asked since it looks like you wrote the answer in 2014. :)

Comment: I wanted to answer this myself, but got a phone call in-between. Thanks for answering this!

Comment: Finally had time to put in my own answer. It is possible: use parentheses.

Comment: @Jeroen, there is a check box "Answer your own question" below the question text box. Right now I'm [trying to improve that feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371203/8041231) a bit.

Comment: @Victoria good idea! I had most of the answer ready when asking, but got interrupted, so decided to post anyway to see if others had a different solution, then later decided to make the answer more readable. Let me know how I can improve it further.

Comment: @Jeroen, aha, well I would personally post them at once as it may lead to confusion (like in this answer Brian links your own blog post :) Your answer is nicely written! And I would keep it as it is. Already upvoted..